# Cgroups I/O read restriction

Tags: usability, io, cgroup

I am trying to restrict group to read operation to 100 per second.

Here is my cgroups configuration:

```
# Configuration file generated by cgsnapshot
mount { 

    blkio = /cgroup/blkio;      
}

group test2 {   
    blkio {
        blkio.throttle.write_iops_device="8:0 100";
        blkio.throttle.read_iops_device="8:0 100";
        blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="8:0 10485760";
        blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="8:0 10485760";
        blkio.weight="";
        blkio.weight_device="";
    }
}
```

Read operation restrict to around 1 minute after that will read up to 10MB/s.

I am running the dd command to test as test2 user:

dd if=file_1 of=file_2

Here is the output of iotop command:

```
 Total DISK READ: 396.82 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s   TID  PRIO 
 USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND  7801 be/4
 test2     396.82 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 96.32 % dd of=/de~ if=file_1 
 5897 be/4 test2       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % -bash
```

Here is the output after 1 minute:

```
Total DISK READ: 9.89 M/s | Total DISK WRITE: 3.96 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 7801 be/4 test2       9.89 M/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 93.64 % dd of=/de~ if=file_1
 5897 be/4 test2       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % -bash
```

It will restrict as per my blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="8:0 10485760" configuration?

What i am missing?

And also one more question tah dd write command will not restricted using this configuration?